# How to use bash `compgen` with my own script options?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion, compgen

I am new to `compgen` and want to use it for a script I am working on. This script can have "commands" and "options" as arguments like so:

```sh
script add "value"
script --path "/a/file/path" add "value"
# and others
```

I wrote a completion script that looks like that:

```sh
_script_completions() {
    arg_index="${COMP_CWORD}"
    if [[ "${arg_index}" -eq 1 ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--path add" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
    fi
}
complete -F _script_completions script
```

This script is working fine for the "add" command but fails on the "--path" option. For example:
When I enter:

```sh
$ script --p<TAB>
```

I get:

```sh
$ ./script --pbash: compgen: --: invalid option
compgen: usage: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [word]
```

How do I add the completion for my own script options correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `compgen -W "--path add" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"` and `script --p<tab>` the last argument `${COMP_WORDS[1]}` turns into `--p` and is then interpreted as an option for `compgen` instead of the word to complete. You can use the argument `--` to mark the end of options:

```
_script_completions() {
    arg_index="${COMP_CWORD}"
    if [[ "${arg_index}" -eq 1 ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--path add" -- "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
    fi
}
complete -F _script_completions script
```